# Checking front and backend

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say that I have a text input that I don't want to be empty. I can check it through Js and tell the user a message.

As much as I've heard, this isn't very secure and we should check in the backend, too. My question is, if I check that the field is empty through PhP, wouldn't the message that I tell the user from PhP overlap the Js one?

Comment: client-side validation would be the first check, before it is submitted to the server.  Then, you'd perform a second check on the server.  Normally, there would be no overlap, *if* everything is working correctly.

Comment: Why would the messages overlap?  If the JavaScript says the field isn't valid, then it shouldn't even be sent to PHP, right?

Comment: Simple answer.  No it would not need to.   But that is not the answer your looking for.  What have you tried?

Comment: Ideally, No. Because, frontend check will not user pass through if the field is not filled.

Comment: But can't people run their own scripts and try to bypass the frontend validation?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: Yeah, and that's where the backend validation comes into play.  But in that case, there still would be no overlap of messages.  If they are bypassing the frontend validation, then that's they won't see the message anyway.

Comment: If they will bypass the frontend validation, then they can see only server side validation message. not frontend one. :p

Comment: Then, where do I output the message that results through the backend validation?

Comment: you can put a span container for the backend error message besides your text field.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: That's up to you.  Do you even need to show them?  The only time they'll be useful is if a user is up to no good, right?  (Or maybe if they have JavaScript off.)  How do you display the JavaScript ones?  Just show the server-side ones in the same way.

Comment: I see. Thought there was some special or regular way to do it than simply outputting in the same div.

Comment: Presenting backend validation response to the user depends on how the PHP (server) script is accessed. If by a page reload the PHP can write the response into the HTML, OR if by an AJAX call then use Javascript to write the message to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't overlap eachother. The reason you will have to validate it backend too is because if you disable JavaScript those frontend validations won't work.

I will give you an example, using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Lets say we have the following HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <?php $error ? $error : '' ?>
</form>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

And the following PHP:

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];

// Validate if fields are matching requirements

if (// Validation fails) 
{
    $error = 'Some fields are invalid';
}
```

This is some really poor validation but it's an example.

So this way if the JavaScript does not get executed, PHP will return $error with the error messages.

If you don't know what `$error ? $error : ''` means, it an equivalent of:

```
if ($error) {
    echo $error;
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Hope this helps you.